# How to parse wordpress taxonomy database content in python

Tags: python, wordpress

This is a dump of row from postmeta table in wordpress database

How to parse this data out side of wordpress in python.

```
a:17:{s:13:"pa_tea-coffee";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:13:"pa_tea-coffee";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"0";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:24:"pa_bottled-mineral-water";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:24:"pa_bottled-mineral-water";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"1";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:17:"pa_drinking-water";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:17:"pa_drinking-water";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"2";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:8:"pa_wi-fi";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:8:"pa_wi-fi";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"3";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:7:"pa_cctv";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:7:"pa_cctv";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"4";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:20:"pa_security-services";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:20:"pa_security-services";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"5";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:27:"pa_fire_fighting_equipmment";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:27:"pa_fire_fighting_equipmment";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"6";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:25:"pa_fire-alarms-sprinklers";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:25:"pa_fire-alarms-sprinklers";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"7";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:21:"pa_reception-services";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:21:"pa_reception-services";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"8";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:24:"pa_housekeeping-services";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:24:"pa_housekeeping-services";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"9";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:17:"pa_centralized-ac";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:17:"pa_centralized-ac";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:2:"10";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:23:"pa_multiple-powerpoints";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:23:"pa_multiple-powerpoints";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:2:"11";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:23:"pa_train-station-access";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:23:"pa_train-station-access";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:2:"12";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:14:"pa_ups-back-up";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:14:"pa_ups-back-up";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:2:"13";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:20:"pa_4-wheeler-parking";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:20:"pa_4-wheeler-parking";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:2:"14";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:20:"pa_2-wheeler-parking";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:20:"pa_2-wheeler-parking";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:2:"15";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:17:"pa_public-parking";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:17:"pa_public-parking";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:2:"16";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}}
```

Unable to do it using python - phpserialize package

Trackeback of Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cj/projects/scripts/usageTypes.py", line 53, in <module>
    products = getProducts()
  File "/home/cj/projects/scripts/usageTypes.py", line 50, in getProducts
    products = build_product_dict(products)
  File "/home/cj/projects/scripts/usageTypes.py", line 44, in build_product_dict
    products[current_post_id]['additional_attr'][row['meta_key']]= phpserialize.unserialize(row['meta_value'])
  File "/home/cj/.vtenv/scripts/lib/python3.5/site-packages/phpserialize.py", line 521, in loads
    return load(BytesIO(data), charset, errors, decode_strings,
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress stores it's data as PHP serialized data, a format that is largely unused now thanks to JSON. It was quite popular among PHP developers at one stage during the good old days (hint, wordpress is ancient history).

It fell into disuse because there are some security concerns with php serialize and unserialize and also because of the rise of JSON. However it's still found in some apps.

use [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to convert to a php object

> unserialize — Creates a PHP value from a stored representation

The above whould yield something like:

```
array(17) {
  ["pa_tea-coffee"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "pa_tea-coffee"
    ["value"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["is_visible"]=>
    int(1)
    ["is_variation"]=>
    int(0)
    ["is_taxonomy"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  ["pa_bottled-mineral-water"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(24) "pa_bottled-mineral-water"
    ["value"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["is_visible"]=>
    int(1)
    ["is_variation"]=>
    int(0)
    ["is_taxonomy"]=>
    int(1
```

how to convert this into python, well that's another problem because this is not native to python. But fortunately, there are modules like this one: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/phpserialize

Comment: I was not able to use it

Comment: what does that mean

Comment: just posted the traceback

Comment: Sorry making a drastic change to a question invalidate an answer is not on. I answered the original question you asked

Comment: no sorry, it's my bad. I think you have a legit reason to edit the question. I have rolled by my edit and your edit now stands.

Comment: but do also add the relevent part of your code that is referred to in the stacktrace

Comment: Is this sorted out?